# Can't add gradient shape to background of layout: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, gradient

I'm trying to add a gradient to the background of a LinearLayout, and it is giving me a ClassNotFoundException.

Here is the layout:
res/drawable/blue_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#003399" 
        android:endColor="#002288"
        android:angle="270"
     />
</shape>
```

res/layout/main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
```

Here is the exception:

```
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kizbit.pairfinder/com.kizbit.pairfinder.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class shape
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class shape
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.kizbit.pairfinder.Main.onCreate(Main.java:38)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     ... 11 more
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.shape in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.kizbit.pairfinder-1.apk]
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
03-31 23:21:14.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: Not sure where `android.view.shape` comes from, as `Shape` should be in `android.graphics.drawable.*`. Have you tried a 'clean' on your project, assuming you're using Eclipse?

Comment: Ha! I was in the middle of 'ant clean' when I read your comment! It worked! You win! That is just so dumb. These tools need to be more robust!

Comment: The above implementation is right might any problem in your cod ecan you give a snippet of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ant clean` fixed it!

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 21